# Use a SharePoint HyperLink column in a redirect on the dispform page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

I have an issue where I do not want people to reach to dispform.aspx page I want them to be redirected to the proper page which holds the item they should see instead.

The list has a column (URL) in it that holds the URL I want the end user to be redirected to. There will be unlimited URLs as each list item has its own URL.

Is there a way using javascript and or JQuery to redirect the end user?

How would I use the hyperlink URL column or convert it to a text column to be used as the redirect URL?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      <a href= {window.location="<a href="javascript:{{ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent 
       ('__redirect={{DispForm.aspx?url={@urlcolumn}}})}}}</a>";

</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Redirect() {
  var1 = "url column"
  window.location="var1";
}
</script>
```

Thanks for the help, as I'm not sure how to achieve this solution I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using JS Link to achieve this functionality.

```
(function () {

    var requestCtx = {};
    requestCtx.Templates = {};

    requestCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        'LinkTitle': {'View': titleFieldTemplate}   
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(requestCtx);

})();

function titleFieldTemplate(ctx) {
    var id = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
    var title = ctx.CurrentItem.Title;

    return '<a href="' + _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + '/testpage.aspx?itemId=' + id + '">' + title + '</a>';
}
```

You can have this script in a JS file and refer the path under list view web part properties (Miscellaneous -> JS Link)

You can replace with your field internal name and url.

Comment: the urls are always different...
questions about these two vars
var id = ctx.Currentitem.ID ; this is the id of the list item?
 var title = ctx.currentitem.Title;   I take that is the title column?

Question:
the url column in my list has exactly where I want to end user to be redirected to.  Would I need the '/testpage.aspx?  
Would I put this in the dispform.aspx page?

Comment: How do you know the URL for a record. Is there any field in a list item has that URL?

Comment: Yes, the url is always in the list and each list item has it's own url.
I need to redirect people from the dispform to the url that is stored in the list in the column URL. there could be several 1000 urls in the list

Comment: In this case, you have to change your logic in the `titleFieldTemplate` method. You can get the URL in this method using `var url = ctx.CurrentItem["youfieldname"]` and replace `return '<a href="' + url + '">text you want to display</a>'`

Comment: thanks, the field name is that the same as the column name?  how do I get the ctx. name of a column? if I need the ctx value instead of the column name.
I was wondering about this last question I have: can this be run as a autoredirect?  I want people to be redirected right away.  I do not need any text basically.. just checking on the redirect part

Comment: The `youfieldname` is an Internal Name of the field. Can you explain further on aut redirect?

Comment: how do I get the internal name of a column?  as far as the redirect, I do not people to go to the display page at all, I want to have people when they click a link that is to take them to the dispform.aspx  be routed to the page url that is stored in the "url of business" column.

Comment: Go to List Settings -> Click on the field you want to customize. From the browser address bar, you will a Name of that selected field. Coming to hyperlink, in my example, it is a customization redirect to the custom page when clicking on a link title on a All Items view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSLink. Please refer below sample example.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-0a786cdd/sourcecode?fileId=109730&pathId=1836828232